# Strange behavior in C++ using passing by reference?

Tags: c++

For the function:

```
bool compare(const float &a, const float &b)
{
    return a<b;
}
```

when I call it as:

```
compare(1.0f,2.0f);
```

And when I set a breakpoint inside the function compare, I notice the value a, b are randomly modified, is this normal? I am using a gcc with Qt creator.

Comment: what does 'randomly modified' mean?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any issue with your code. Try printing the values inside compare function instead of checking them in your debugger.

Answer (score 5):

This is perfectly legal C++: anonymous temporary literals are allowed to bind to `const` references of the same type.

Your IDE is clearly displaying something else.

Comment: @codekaizer: Yup, I've cast a delete vote on that question. One more to go.